# Attribute and Type Error using Button class in Tkinter/GPIO Zero combination

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, gpiozero, tkinter

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to write a simple program to change the blink rate of an LED using a GUI.

When I try to run this on my RaspberryPi 2B running Raspbian, I get the following error that I don't understand:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'Button' object has no attribute '_hold_thread'" in Traceback (most recent call last)
```

and then

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'
```

To me this says that width is not a valid argument, but I ran another program on my Pi using width and it worked.

Code follows:

```
# This program will create an interactive GUI which can change an LED's blink rate

# Import necessary modules
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import *

# Set up GUI Window
mygui = Tk()
myfont = ('Times', 24, 'bold')
myfont2 = ('Times', 36, 'bold')
mygui.title('LED Controller')
mygui.geometry('640x480+120+120')
counter = IntVar()
red_LED = LED(17)

while True:

    # Define usable functions
    def increase_speed():
        counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
        print(counter.get())


    def decrease_speed():
        counter.set(counter.get() - 1)
        print(counter.get())


    def end_program():
        mygui.destroy()


    # Create GUI labels
    label1 = Label(mygui, text='Increase Blink Speed', padx=15, pady=15, font=myfont)
    label1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    label2 = Label(mygui, text='Decrease Blink Speed', padx=15, pady=15, font=myfont)
    label2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)


    # Create GUI buttons
    button1 = Button(mygui, text='+', font=myfont2, command=increase_speed, fg='green', width=5)
    button1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
    button2 = Button(mygui, text='-', font=myfont2, command=decrease_speed, fg='red', width=5)
    button2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
    button3 = Button(mygui, text='Close Window', font=myfont, command=end_program, fg='black', bg='yellow', width=15)
    button3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

    # Turn on LED
    red_LED.on()
    sleep(counter.get())
    red_LED.off()

    mygui.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should include context in error messages if you want help. I suspect your problem is Button in gpoizero is overwriting tkinter. Import * should be used with care.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the response.  I clearly do want help, or else I wouldn't have made this post :) 

I'm not sure what you mean by including the context?  What other information do you need?  

Import* could be the problem, that makes sense!

Comment: I assume Milliways means the full error msg, which includes where the error occurs, etc.

Comment: Ok understood, I will post that next time.  Thanks Dirk!

Comment: As Milliways indicates the most likely error is that you import '*' from gpiozero. \this inludes a Button object which is then used instead of the tkinter version. Just import the LED oject from gpiozero

Comment: I've confirmed that is the correct answer, thank you for the insight Dirk!

Answer (score 2):

Milliways and Dirk are correct, import* was the problem.  I should have realized that both GPIO Zero and Tkinter have a Button class, so one was overwriting the other and causing the error.

Thank you for the help!